# Copy entire javaclass or its parameters without inheritance in Anylogic

Tags: parameters, anylogic

I'm trying to model a factory with production orders in Anylogic. Unfortunately, I'm a beginner in java ...

I created two new JavaClasses for my model. A "bill of material"(stueckliste) and "entry of bill of material"(stuecklisteneintrag). The bill of material has a linked list:

```
String name;
LinkedList<Stuecklisteneintrag>stuecklisteneintrag = new LinkedList<Stuecklisteneintrag>();
```

The "entry of bill of material"(stuecklisteneintrag) class has a lot of parameters.

If i want to create a

```
new Stueckliste();
```

with new entries:

Stuecklisteneintrag stkE = new Stuecklisteneintrag()

based on existing entries:

```
stkE = stueckliste.stuecklisteneintrag.get(test);
```

How do I copy an entire "entry" without the inheritance to the existing entry? Because if i change the parameters, both parameters in the old and new entry will change ...

```
stkE = stueckliste.stuecklisteneintrag.get(test);
a.fertigungsstueckliste.stuecklisteneintrag.add(stkE);
a.fertigungsstueckliste.stuecklisteneintrag.getFirst().name= "Test";
traceln(a.fertigungsstueckliste.stuecklisteneintrag.getFirst().name);
traceln(stueckliste.stuecklisteneintrag.getFirst().name);
```

Both names will be "test". Or if i delete entries in the new bill of material, entrys in the old one are deleted as well ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a "deep copy" of your data. Create a new constructor for `Stuecklisteneintrag` as:

```
public Stuecklisteneintrag(Stuecklisteneintrag oldEintrag) {
    this.field1 = oldEintrag.field1;
    ... // add all fields here
}
```

This will create a new `Stuecklisteneintrag` instance that takes from the `oldEintrag` instance but they are now "de-coupled" :)

NOTE: You can only do this for `primitive` data types (int, double, boolean) as well as for `String`s. If you have fields that are other Java classes, they need deep copies as well!

Comment: Lovely. Please upvote the reply so others with similar issues can find it easier in the future, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote